# What is the default repository in command "git ls-remote --tags"

Tags: git

In Git's manual page, `<repository>` argument in `ls-remote` command is optional. But it does not specify the behavior when it is not given.

A few testings seems to show that Git uses `origin` as the default (Yes, I have multiple remote repositories).  When `origin` remote repository does not exist, it seems to return an error message `fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.`

Yet my tests are finite (and no way to test infinite cases).  So, can anyone confirm that the default is in deed `origin`?

Or, is any command I neglected, which sets the default repository mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, can anyone confirm that the default is in deed `origin`?

The sources from Git itself can confirm that.

For instance, see [`git/git/t/t5512-ls-remote.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4123bcaed0897cad152c052a5fa4e499e4dafcf4/t/t5512-ls-remote.sh#L42-L46)

```
test_expect_success 'dies when no remote specified and no default remotes found' '
    test_must_fail git ls-remote
'
test_expect_success 'use "origin" when no remote specified' '
```

But the [same tests includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4123bcaed0897cad152c052a5fa4e499e4dafcf4/t/t5512-ls-remote.sh#L62-L66):

```
test_expect_success 'use branch.<name>.remote if possible' '
    #
    # Test that we are indeed using branch.<name>.remote, not "origin", even
    # though the "origin" remote has been set.
    #
```

**So the *actual* default for [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) is the upstream branch remote** (or origin is no upstream branch was associated to the current branch)

```
git config branch.<name>.remote
```